# Can I have random points as well as Circles on a plot in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

as an example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
pointx = random.random()
pointy = random.random()
plt.scatter(pointx , pointy)

circle = plt.Circle((.5,.55) , .07,color='b')
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(circle)

plt.show()
```

I only get the random xy point when I do this but when I remove the random xy point I get the circle. What can I do so I have both on one plot?

Comment: Is it just drawing the circle over top of the point? try reversing the order.

Comment: You can also pass the kwarg `zorder=` to the plotting commands to specify the order in which the artists are drawn to the canvas

Comment: @Octopus - would you mind making your comment an answer so that it can be accepted? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your circle is being plotted on top of your point try reversing it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

circle = plt.Circle((.5,.55) , .07,color='b')
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(circle)

pointx = random.random()
pointy = random.random()
plt.scatter(pointx , pointy)

plt.show()
```